# Signing a transaction with openSSL

Tags: input-script

I've read a bit about signing a transaction using openSSL, I've tried implementing it but it seems like the signatures generated are not accepted. So I'm wondering if the following commands provide a valid signature.

Let's create a private key: `dd1cd59c4de2fa92e363dac282afe790a5193177d413b38e206b2b86b879ffbf`
And generate a testnet public address: `mhZQtrhzjqkDmm8yp8jR2D84AagCdL4YzM`
And send some testnet btc to it: `a05f60a9679a1ad0ef57b092006b6c01886291a2ff696f5e2ac107b349594cf6`

We will create a transaction that sends the BTC to `2N8hwP1WmJrFF5QWABn38y63uYLhnJYJYTF`.

Okay, so the unsigned raw transaction is:

`01000000
01
f64c5949b307c12a5e6f69ffa2916288016c6b0092b057efd01a9a67a9605fa0
00000000
19
166749c16df955750990623397be66e965863611
ffffffff
01
70508e0600000000
1976a914a9974100aeee974a20cda9a2f545704a0ab54fdc88ac
00000000
01000000`

We double hash the raw transaction: `372f7f092abc73c2bcd357ec2b0dab4a9fdbb956771c676cf92a899feedcda0a`.
And create a PEM key for openSSL (30740201010420 . private_key . a00706052b8104000aa144034200 . public_key and base64 it): 

`-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY----- MHQCAQEEIN0c1ZxN4vqS42PawoKv55ClGTF31BOzjiBrK4a4ef+/oAcGBSuBBAAK oUQDQgAEnQ9w7thTRcpcHARWO+0ZYIViw31kQGF4WoNujxmRVfKBih4mYfntUB2P kGYRiSCZqd5afqn2Qey03XW7tjwtWg==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----`

And then I use the following command to create the DER sig: `echo "372f7f092abc73c2bcd357ec2b0dab4a9fdbb956771c676cf92a899feedcda0a" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hex -sign key.pem`.

Adding the length byte and public key, we end up with the following scriptSig: `46 304402203c8aaa41ae647149f70ce24f73109e99d59d7e54a5d854239943358d581e9f8302206336cb57c00bb78f46c881b3d6bb2ed76dc652eedf36064ae022ea4ae3ba3b100141049d0f70eed85345ca5c1c 04 563bed19608562c37d644061785a836e8f199155f2818a1e2661f9ed501d8f906611892099a9de5a7ea9f641ecb4dd75bbb63c2d5a`.

Great. This leaves us with the following raw transaction:

`01000000
01
f64c5949b307c12a5e6f69ffa2916288016c6b0092b057efd01a9a67a9605fa0
00000000
8a
47304402203c8aaa41ae647149f70ce24f73109e99d59d7e54a5d854239943358d581e9f8302206336cb57c00bb78f46c881b3d6bb2ed76dc652eedf36064ae022ea4ae3ba3b100141049d0f70eed85345ca5c1c04563bed19608562c37d644061785a836e8f199155f2818a1e2661f9ed501d8f906611892099a9de5a7ea9f641ecb4dd75bbb63c2d5a
ffffffff
01
70508e0600000000
1976a914a9974100aeee974a20cda9a2f545704a0ab54fdc88ac
00000000`

Which is unfortunately not a valid transaction (error received: `PUSH TRANSACTION ERROR: 16: MANDATORY-SCRIPT-VERIFY-FLAG-FAILED (OPCODE MISSING OR NOT UNDERSTOOD)`).

Using a transaction tool, I get the following (valid) raw transaction, which I was able to redeem:

`01000000
01
f64c5949b307c12a5e6f69ffa2916288016c6b0092b057efd01a9a67a9605fa0
00000000
8a
47304402204cdb6499578276106748c4877bf2a3381ba484fb621ce8d3faa2161254bdeec902205e3536aeaa65f8f0f55b3eb31a9bf8959b70e247c0ebd9da485e586370a25b900141 049d0f70eed85345ca5c1c04563bed19608562c37d644061785a836e8f199155f2818a1e2661f9ed501d8f906611892099a9de5a7ea9f641ecb4dd75bbb63c2d5a
ffffffff
01
70508e0600000000
1976a914a9974100aeee974a20cda9a2f545704a0ab54fdc88ac
00000000`

All the fields are correct besides the signature. How come the openSSL signing command I used was incorrect?

Is the signature generated valid? Is the openSSL command valid? Can we even use openSSL to sign a transaction?

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't verified the signature, upon inspection of the encoding I think I can see what is wrong. Let's break down the scriptSig briefly and I'll show you:

```
8a (total number of bytes to follow)
46 (the signature is 0x46 bytes long *THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUE IS*)
30 (compound DER type)
44 (0x44 bytes following)
02 (integer type)
20 (0x20 bytes long)
3c8aaa41ae647149f70ce24f73109e99d59d7e54a5d854239943358d581e9f83 (R value)
02 (integer type)
20 (0x20 bytes long)
6336cb57c00bb78f46c881b3d6bb2ed76dc652eedf36064ae022ea4ae3ba3b10 (S value)
01 (SIGHASH_ALL sighash type)
41 (length of public key is 0x41 bytes)
049d0f70eed85345ca5c1c04563bed19608562c37d644061785a836e8f199155f2818a1e2661f9ed501d8f906611892099a9de5a7ea9f641ecb4dd75bbb63c2d5a (public key)
```

Now I've highlighted the length of the DER encoded signature as the issue - `46`. This should be `47`. The reason is that that length is actually supposed to be the length of the signature **plus one byte for the sighash type**. Unlike normal DER signature produced by OpenSSL, Bitcoin requires the sighash type to be appended, in this case `01` for SIGHASH_ALL. You can see the `01` byte present. But you haven't updated the length. In the valid transaction below it, on the other hand, you can see the length is `47` despite the fields being the same length.

So try updating the 46 to a 47 and see if it works :)

Comment: You're correct I did miscalculate the signature length (didn't include the 01). I changed it and try to submit it, but the signature is still not accepted.

Comment: What error do you have now? I cannot help without more info :)

Comment: Hi, I'm getting an error regarding the inputs (which suggest an issue with the signature because when I try to re-submit the same raw transaction, I get an error that the transaction was already broadcasted).

Comment: It could be that it views it as a double spend because you already created a valid transaction afterwards? Make sure the other transaction wasn't broadcast and remove it from your mempool if it is there

Comment: When the signature is valid, I get an error that the transaction has already been broadcasted (good), but when it's invalid I get a different error. Therefore I know that when my signature is still invalid. Is there a way to verify my signature (using an online tool or something)?

Comment: Unsure, I haven't seen one before that I can recall. Specifically what error message do you get?